# How to Display "Tabbed" content from Views in Panel / Pane in Node Template

Tags: views, routes, panels

I would like to add a pane with tabbed content to a specific content type/Product display.

Using the guidance provided on drupal.org/node/2209747, I built a series of tabbed content in Views, using "Menu Tab" and creating new pages. (No problem, but not where I want to display the views.)

My goal is to embed this tabbed content into a pane (in Panels Node Template). However, when I select the view, I am required to specify either "Master", "Page 1", "Topic A", or "Topic B".

These options remove the tabs and either show all content (Master/Page 1) or filter content (Topic A or Topic B).

1. Is there a way to embed the tabbed view using only the Views module?
2. Should I create a Content Pane, instead of a page?
3. Can I avoid using an additional module like Quicktabs?

I assume that I am running into trouble because the tabbed view depends on the url path differentiation and cannot work when dropped into a pane. (At least with my current approach.)

Any help is appreciated!
keb

[image: Edit View // Showing Menu Tab approach]
[image: Comparison of URL output vs. In Pane / Node Template]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used the "[Panel Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_tabs)" module. It is available in dev version, which gave me pause, but it works well on the main platforms (Chrome / iE / Firefox); I haven't played around on Safari.

With a little css, this will be a good working solution, but I would be interested to know if others have a more standard approach.

Thanks,
keb
[image]